# Query String Parameter in Workday

Tags: workday-api

We are routing people from an external domain to Workday for completing their profile and having issues tracking them. We are able to send query string parameters to workday. Is there a way to store these qsps in Workday to help connect the IDs across domains?

We are able to persist QSPs across domains and not lose them but we are not able to store them on workday

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in Other ID's in Workday